# Intellij IDEA - Find in path string literal, how to avoid interpretation as a regex?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am trying to find the string `${project.version}` in all my `pom.xml` files,  and replace it with something else. However, IDEA's **Find in path** feature is treating this as a regex and therefore complains that it is malformed. I need some escape characters I think, but can't find what they are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should not try to parse it as a regexp. Just tried it out. Make sure "Regular Expression" is not selected in the find window.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about that checkbox! In the latest version of the IDE it has moved to the top of that dialogue window.